# Какие программы существуют для проверки включенности компьютера в локальной сети и включение или предупреждение пользователя?

Tags: windows, сервер

Уезжаю в армию, и голова немного не варит, не могу найти программу, которая заменяла бы watchdog для локального сервера, так как тот не просыпается сам без родного chasis-a, а стоит в обычном корпусе.
Посоветуйте программы для проверки локального ПК и включения по сети, или предупреждения пользователя под Windows 10 (не про), пожалуйста.

Comment: `ping+wakeonlan`?